# Unix script shows last created file that can be occur unknown time

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting, sh

I prepared a script that can check display last created file.

**file_to_search=`find /var/lib/occas/domains/domain1/servers/traffic-1/logs/ -name "traffic-1.log*" 2>/dev/null | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d" "`
grep "Event: Invoke          :" $file_to_search  | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ">" } ; { print $1 }' | sort | uniq -ic >> /home/appuser/scripts/Traffic/EventInvoke_pl-1_Istanbul.txt.backup.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")**

I have following log files in this path: /var/lib/occas/domains/domain1/servers/traffic-1/logs/ but these files are being created changeable period. So, if I put this script to crontab for example 5 minutes, it can show same sometimes file and this is not what i want. I need a script that is showing last created file but when the file occurs. Help me, please?

```
10:54 traffic-1.log00023
11:01 traffic-1.log00024
11:05 traffic-1.log00025
11:06 traffic-1.log00026
11:09 traffic-1.log00027
11:18 traffic-1.log00028
11:23 traffic-1.log00029
11:34 traffic-1.log00030
11:39 traffic-1.log00031
11:40 traffic-1.log00032
```

Answer (score 0):

How much delay between the generation of the log entry and the display would you be willing to take? In theory, you could start the cron job every minute, but I wouldn't do this.

Much easier would be a script which runs unattended and, in a loop, repeatedly checks the last line of the log file, and if it changes, does whatever needs to be done.

There are however two issues to observe:

The first is easy: You should at least sleep for 1 or 2 seconds after each "polling", otherwise your script will eat up a lot of system resources.

The second is a bit tricky: It could be, that your script terminates for whatever reason, and it this happens, you need to have it restarted automatically. One way would be to set up a "watchdog": Your script, in addition to checking the log file, touches a certain file every time it did the checking (no matter whether a new event need to be reported or not). The watchdog, which could be a cron job running every, say, 10 minutes, would verify that your script is still alive (i.e. that the output file of your script had been touched during the past couple of seconds), and if not, would start a new copy of your script. This means that you could loose a 10 minute timewindow, but since it is likely a very rare event, that your script crashes, this will, hopefully, not an issue.